# How do I delete origin/master in Git

Tags: git

I cannot remove `origin/master` from my server. No idea why.

[image: Screenshot of my terminal]

The error message is the following

```
remote: error: By default, deleting the current branch is denied, because the next
remote: error: 'git clone' won't result in any file checked out, causing confusion.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyDeleteCurrent' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'warn' or 'ignore' in the remote repository to allow deleting the
remote: error: current branch, with or without a warning message.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message, you can set it to 'refuse'.
remote: error: refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master
To acanzian@elab.ecn.purdue.edu:/export/home/a/elabshare/git/ID-check.git
 ! [remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited)
error: failed to push some refs to 'acanzian@elab.ecn.purdue.edu:/export/home/a/elabshare/git/ID-check.git'
```

No, I am **not** using *Github*.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Are there other branches?

Comment: Indeed there are other branches (check the link to the image, actually, could you display it for me, please?). We had to rebase `master`, and we did it on a temporal branch which now should become `master`. The only problem is that I don't know why I cannot kill master on the server.

Comment: Maybe not the answer you're looking for, but you could force-push the rebased `master` to `origin/master`, effectively replacing the old one with the new one.

Comment: In addition to the error message, please post the command you're using.

Comment: @Kyralessa, check the screenshot.

Comment: @SlightlyCuban, I was trying to avoid *forcing* stuff and find instead a "clean" way :)

Comment: You're not the only one I've seen with the notion that "force" is a terrible or messy thing to do.  We're always told not to force things.  Forcing a door knob might break it.  Forcing a screw might strip the head.  But forcing Git isn't going to do any damage, as long as you're aware of what commits it'll replace.  You won't mess up Git or break it or leave it unable to function.  Having to put `-f` is just a way of saying, "I realize that when doing this, I *could* lose work, but I know what I'm doing, so go ahead and do it anyway."

Comment: @Atcold, I don't normally recommend forcing, but it sounded like you were going to point `master` to a different branch anyway. In this case, `--force` and `delete && push` would have the same end-result. The only difference: deleting would be a 2-step operation, which might be cleaner if you didn't plan to push immediately after.

Comment: @SlightlyCuban, my first concern was understanding why my machine was not bending to my will. Now I'm her master again! :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Fun fact: even remote, [bare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7632497/605356) repositories are on a branch. You're getting rejected because you're trying to delete the branch that your origin has currently "checked out".

If you have direct, filesystem-access to the repo:

1. You can just open up a shell to the bare repo directory and use good old `git branch` to see what branch origin is currently on (if any; see below). To change it to another branch, you have to use [`git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/<another_branch>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3302018/2372767).
2. In some unusual scenarios, including when the default branch is renamed, a [bare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7632497/605356) repo has no current, "checked out," default branch. In such a case, `git branch | grep '^*'` run from the bare repo directory will print nothing (the default branch has a `*` to the left of the default-branch name), and you can run the above `git symbolic-ref ...` command to select a default branch. (Also: you can run `git branch <new_branch>` to create a new one, if needed, but a default/current branch has to first be selected.)

If you are using a service like Github or Gitorious, you're going to have to use the UI the tool provides you to make the change (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2962737/2372767) for how to do that in common tools).

Comment: Awesome, it worked and it gave me the chance of learning more about `refs` in *Git*! Thank you very much! (Yeah, I knew about how to deal with it on *Github*, but not on our personal server.)

Answer (score 16):

In lieu of actually removing master from the server, you can replace it like this:

```
git push origin otherbranch:master -f
```

That will replace master with the contents of otherbranch, but it'll still be called master on the remote.  And then you can check out master as master in your local.

Comment: OK, thanks! I know I can force stuff, but I was wondering exactly why I couldn't remove the `master` branch, and the accepted answer explains why.

Comment: +1. This was the only way I could delete a bad first commit on remotes/origin/master.